# IIS sending back a 401 for intranet site unless the client logs out and back in again after leaving machine unlocked over night

Tags: iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I don't believe the issue is the server.  I suspect the kerberos token is expiring on the client workstation and is not automatically renewing until they either lock and then unlock their PC, or log out and back into windows.  is there any way to work around this?

The only group policy i could find is this one:
Interactive logon: Require Domain Controller authentication to unlock workstation

The other interesting thing is if i remote desktop into their pc using their session (their credentials), the website will work again, so we get 200s instead of 401s, so i know it has something to do with their windows session expiring.

So my question is this:  Is there a policy out there that can prevent the session from expiring since the users never lock their machines or at the very least, what can be done to automatically renew it so that they don't have to keep locking their machines or relogging back into windows

Comment: Hi Richard.  Please edit your question to show a screenshot of your domain Kerberos policy.  These policy settings are located at \Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Kerberos Policy.

Comment: Are you the Active Directory admin at this location or are you on more of the DevOps side without admin access to AD?

Comment: The kerberos policy is hidden under account policies.  I do not have access to it, but I've sent email off requesting access or information from them.   I'm not sure I'll even get this information unfortunately.  Is there anything else i can do on my end or prove that this is the issue?  and im just on devops end

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I will repro this issue to validate it and get back to you.  Give me a few days on it though.